# Story Points in Sprint Taskboards instead of effort

Tags: azure-devops

we just started with Azure DevOps to visualize our Backlog and our Sprints. Before we worked with Youtrack. We tried to change in the columns of the Sprint Taskboard the sum of effort into Story Points. Any suggestion, how we can solve this?

- We changed the process to scrum
- We searched in the processes under organisation settings and created an own scrum process
- We created custom tasks for Sprint Taskboards called "User Stories"
- We added the field for Story Points to the cards

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, I sent a ticket to Microsoft and surprise: I got an answer!

The support answered:

> Hi Peter,
>
> I am sorry the feature to show the sum of story points in the column-headers of a sprint taskboard is not available, but as per the discussion at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365443/display-sum-of-story-points-in-a-sprint-agile-temp.html the product group is looking at implementing the feature.
>
> Please follow the above link to get the latest update on the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Is the **effort** group you want to replace referring to **Remaining work** field?
[image]

In scrum process , it shows like this :

[image]

In agile process , it shows like this :

[image]

Of course, the name and field are all customizable. If this refers to the remaining work field, you want to replace this with story points. According to your information, we can know that you have added Story Points field to the cards. Then what you need is not display the remaining work field , you can set it up in settings.

[image]

If I misunderstood ，please point out and i will edit this answer.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed reply. The description of my story was not detailed enough :) ... i want to change the metric effort or remaining work in the column-header of the Sprint Taskboard to Story Points.